# How to get xcom value in normal function or how to use pubsubOperator

Tags: airflow

I am trying to pass xcom value to normal function but it is passing the actual value

I tried with below using sample code

```
def getArgsForPractice(practice, messageId, status_result):
    practice_args = dict()
    practice_args['practice_id'] = practice
    practice_args['message_id'] = messageId
    practice_args['status'] = status_result
    practice_args_json = json.dumps(practice_args)
    message = {'data': base64.b64encode(practice_args_json.encode('utf-8')).decode()}
    return message

PubSubPublishSuccess = PubSubPublishOperator(task_id='publish-messages_success',
    topic=PUB_SUB_TOPIC,
    project=PROJECT_ID,
    messages=[
        getArgsForPractice(
            "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_practice_id_task', key='return_value')[0]}}",
            "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_measure_id_task', key='return_value')[0]}}",
            "SUCCESS"
        )
    ],
    dag=dag)
```

I seen the output value below like this enter code here:

```
{"practice_id": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_practice_id_task',     key='return_value')[0]}}", "message_id": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('get_measure_id_task', key='return_value')[0]}}", "status": "SUCCESS"} │ 599454601822320 │
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the expected output here. Can you please explain?

Comment: @nightgaunt..i want to get the below string from getArgsForPractice this function.the retrun encoded string i need to give pub sub operator message.


{'data':{"practice_id": "aaaa", "message_id": "640965002374008", "status": "FAILED"}}